# Que signifie "en" ici ?

Tags: grammaire, en

Bonjour,

Je ne comprends pas très bien ce passage dans *Féerie pour une autre fois* I :

> Ah jouisserie néon ! la folichonnerie totale ! Ah cocotte ! Ah
> m'aime-moi ! m'aime ! Ah, prends m'**en** tout ! m'enmour ! enmour ! **en !
> en ! en !** t'**en** as quatre ! dix ! vingt ! cent ! grosses ! Ah ! Oh ! Hu
> ! **en** ! tout !

La traduction anglaise propose :

> Ah, coming in neon lights! the ultimate frolic! Ah, honey-bunch, love
> me, baby, love me! Ah, take all of me! **in** love me! **in** love me! **in! in!**
> **in!** you've got four of them! ten! twenty! a hundred! big ones! Oh!
> Ooo! Whooo! **in**! all of it!

Que signifie *en* dans ***en ! en ! en !*** et ***Hu ! en ! tout !*** ? S'agit-il d'un procédé littéraire pour créer l'effet d'un délire ou le pronom se réfère à un antécédent ?

Answer (score 2):

Je pencherais pour un variante de *han ! han ! han !* mot que le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/han) définit comme:

> *Onomatopée* [Reproduit le cri sourd accompagnant une expiration profonde et brusquement interrompue d'une personne accomplissant un effort violent]